# Exercise 8, Section 3.1 of Hoffman’s Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification, proof-writing, linear-transformations

> Describe explicitly a linear transformation from $\Bbb{R}^3$ into $\Bbb{R}^3$ which has as its range the subspace spanned by $(1,0,-1)$ and $(1,2,2)$.

We can prove a stronger result:

> Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over field $F$ with $\mathrm{dim}(V)=n\in \Bbb{N}$ and Let $W$ be a vector space over field $F$. If $(\beta_1,…,\beta_n)$ is sequence in $W$, then $\exists T :V\to W$ such that $T$ is linear map and $\mathrm{span}(\beta_1,…,\beta_n)=R_T$.

**My attempt:** Since $V$ is finite-dimensional vector space with $\mathrm{dim}(V)=n\in \Bbb{N}$, we have $\exists \{\alpha_1,…,\alpha_n\}\subseteq V$ basis of $V$. By theorem 1 section 3.1, $\exists !$ $T\in L(V,W)$ such that $T(\alpha_j)=\beta_j$, $\forall j\in J_n$. Claim: $\mathrm{span}(\beta_1,…,\beta_n)=R_T$. Proof: Let $y\in R_T$. Then $\exists x\in V$ such that $T(x)=y$. Since $\mathrm{span}(\{\alpha_1,…,\alpha_n\})=V$, we have $x=\sum_{i\in J_n}a_i\cdot_V \alpha_i$. So $T(x)=T(\sum_{i\in J_n}a_i\cdot_V \alpha_i)$. Since $T$ is a linear map, we have $T(\sum_{i\in J_n}a_i\cdot_V \alpha_i)$ $=\sum_{i\in J_n}a_i\cdot_W T(\alpha_i)$ $=\sum_{i\in J_n}a_i\cdot_W \beta_i$. Thus $T(x)=y\in \mathrm{span}(\beta_1,…,\beta_n)$. Hence $\mathrm{span}(\beta_1,…,\beta_n)=R_T$. **Is my proof correct?** Proof is basically corollary of theorem 1 section 3.1.

Comment: Your proof is perfect. I think you probably know , if $T$ is injective then $(\beta_1,…,\beta_n)$ will be the basis for $R_T$.

Comment: @LostinSpace I think we have to explicitly say $\beta_i\neq \beta_j$, if $i\neq j$, because injective condition don’t stop us to take same point twice. By rank nullity theorem, dim$(R_T)=$dim$(V)=n$. we can show lots of interesting(elementary) results if we weaken the hypothesis, by saying $T$ is injective, surjective, etc. We are being really “**flexible**” by working with sequence $(\beta_1,…,\beta_n)$, instead of a set. We can make all $\beta_i$ equal and if $T$ is onto, then $\mathrm{span}(\beta_1)=R_T=W$. Though we didn’t define span on a sequence, it is “easily” extended to sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof is incomplete, since you have not shown that every element in the span of $\{\beta_1, ..., \beta_n\}$ is also contained in $R_T$.

To elaborate:
By showing that for any arbitrary $y ∈ R_T$
it is also true that $y∈ $ span$~(\beta_1, ..., _n)$,
you have shown that $R_T ⊆ $ span$~(\beta_1, ..., \beta_n)$.

To prove equality, we need to show the reverse inclusion as well:
Given an element $z∈ $ span$(\beta_1, ..., \beta_n)$
we need to show that it is an element of $R_T$.

Comment: No need to waste time. As $\beta_1,…,\beta_n\in R_T$ and $R_T$ is a subspace. $\text{span}(\beta_1,…,\beta_n)$ is the smallest subspace containing $(\beta_1,…,\beta_n)$ . Hence $\text{span}(\beta_1,…,\beta_n) $ is a subspace of $R_T$ .

Comment: Hey! Welcome to math stack exchange. Yes you’re kind of right. Following is a standard result: Let $V$ be a vector space over field $F$. If $u_1,…,u_k\in V$ ; $k\in \Bbb{N}\cup \{0\}$, then $\mathrm{span}(u_1,…,u_k)\subseteq V$.

Comment: @LostinSpace you’re using smallest subspace definition of span. We can also use set of all linear combinations of $(\beta_1,…,\beta_n)$, as definition of span.